Compacting biological traits arising from emergent biological mechanisms into singular artificial genes
I have scientists attempting to experiment with humans by tampering with sexual attraction for lore reasons. Sexual attraction comes from complex biological mechanisms. They wish to 'simplify' this emergent property by compacting the associated traits into a singular 'sexual attraction gene.'
What are the effect of this gene to give a plausible advantages for the genetically modified population compared to regular humans?

Are your scientists wedded to genetic engineering? This seems like a change that would be easier and more reliable to indoctrinate into people after they're born, while their minds are still plastic enough to be (relatively) easily molded.

simplifying it can't give them an advantage, reproductive success in humans is too tied to highly varaible codtions. reproductive success in humans has to be flexible to be competititve. it like asking how can making the immune system simplier be benefical, short answer it can't.

VTC:NAW per the [help]. This question is hypothetical and open-ended where all answers have equal value... all of which is prohibited in in the [help/dont-ask]. (You graduated this one a bit quickly from the Sandbox. I didn't even get a chance to finish writing my comment.)

@JBH My bad, you commented on my other question  so I assumed you were satisfied

"whatever floats your boat" is the most common way to describe what sexual attraction is. If you want to sound a bit more sophisticated, you can use Latin and say "de gustibus non disputandum est".
Sexual attraction is based on cultural influences and factors, it cannot be boiled down to a gene: blondes are considered top notch beauties in countries where dark/brown hair are predominant, while dark/brown hair are considered very attractive in blondeland.
In countries and times where food is scarce, a fat body is the non plus ultra of attractiveness, while in overfed places a skinny body is yummy.
There is no way to wrap up those tastes into a single gene or a set of genes.

And if you did boil it down that way you'd probably end up killing the human race due to shear boredom.
